# django sitemap: can't pass a variable back from the url

Tags: django, url, routes, sitemap

I'm trying to create a sitemap in django with a dynamic name that i can pass back to my sitemap class. Does anyone know how i can do that in my url pattern?

Url should look like this: 
`/modules-a.xml # where 'a' could be [a-z]`

This is what i'm trying without success:

```
line 20: (r'^modules-(?P<arg>\w+)\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': {'modules': ModuleSitemap(letter)}})
```

Error:

```
Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/modules-a.xml/
Django Version:     1.3.1
Exception Type:     NameError
Exception Value:    

name 'section' is not defined

Exception Location:     /Applications/xampp/xamppfiles/htdocs/myapp/myapp/../myapp/urls.py in <module>, line 20
Python Executable:  /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Resources/Python.app/Contents/MacOS/Python
```

Comment: It helps if you share the specific error message with us. I note that the pattern is not correctly formed. Try using something like `r'^modules-(?P<arg>\w+)\.xml$'`.

Comment: i fixed the format to correctly represent what i have for the url

Comment: sitemaps framework can generate sitemap index files too. and the entries in the index have the similar form: sitemap-???.xml. My guess is that your naming convention interferes with the built in functionality.

Comment: OK. So what does the code at line 20 in `myapp/urls.py` look like? Is there a `section` anywhere in there?

Comment: thats the the route code i pasted.

Comment: What is `letter` in your code?

Answer (score 1):

According to [sitemap framework doc](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/sitemaps/#creating-a-sitemap-index) the`sitemap` view should take a **section** keyword argument.

I belive you need to rename **arg** into **section** in your url:

```
(r'^modules-(?P<section>\w+)\.xml$', 'django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap', {'sitemaps': {'modules': ModuleSitemap(letter)}})
```

Answer (score -3):

I am not 100% sure but I think you have to escape the '-'

change

```
line 20: (r'^modules-(?P<arg>\w+)\.xml$', 'django...
```

to

```
line 20: (r'^modules\-(?P<arg>\w+)\.xml$', 'django...
                    ^
```

Comment: yea, i'm using unescaped - elsewhere in my url routes with no issues

Comment: It is not relevant with "-"